# Работа с константами в javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой объект:

```
var confirmBox = {
   init: function(type, cn_title = false, btn_close = true, btn_title = "OK") {
       var title;
       var CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO,
           CONFIRM_UPDATE_INFO,
           CONFIRM_ALERT_INFO,
           CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR;

       switch (type) {
           case CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO:
               title = "Вы действительно хотите удалить фотографию?";
               break; 
           case CONFIRM_UPDATE_INFO:
               title = "Обновить информацию?";
               break;
           case CONFIRM_ALERT_INFO:
               title = cn_title;
               break;
           case CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR:
               title = "Произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку позже.";
               btn_close = false;
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
       this.show(title, btn_close, btn_title);
   },
   show: function(title, btn_close, btn_title) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Который вызываю так:

```
var CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR;
confirmBox.init(CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR);
```

Но независимо от константы у меня всегда выполняется `case CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO`.

#### Вопрос

Как реализовать правильную передачу константы в функцию `init`? Чтобы, допустим, при передачи константы `CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR` выполнилось то, что указано в `case CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В коде

```
var CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO,
    CONFIRM_UPDATE_INFO,
    CONFIRM_ALERT_INFO,
    CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR;
```

Вы объявляете переменные, но не указываете их значения.

Вам необходимо вынести инициализацию "констант" за функцию и дать им значения.

Пример:

```
var CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO = 1,
    CONFIRM_UPDATE_INFO = 2,
    CONFIRM_ALERT_INFO = 3,
    CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR = 4;

var confirmBox = {
   init: function(type, cn_title = false, btn_close = true, btn_title = "OK") {
       var title;

       switch (type) {
           case CONFIRM_DELETE_PHOTO:
               title = "Вы действительно хотите удалить фотографию?";
               break; 
           case CONFIRM_UPDATE_INFO:
               title = "Обновить информацию?";
               break;
           case CONFIRM_ALERT_INFO:
               title = cn_title;
               break;
           case CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR:
               title = "Произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку позже.";
               btn_close = false;
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }

       this.show(title, btn_close, btn_title);
   },
   show: function(title, btn_close, btn_title) {
       ...
   }
}

confirmBox.init(CONFIRM_ALERT_ERROR);
```

Comment: да, действительно.. Спасибо!